# Is it possible to get interactive feedback with python's Pool.map()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

I have something that looks like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def handle_element((element, params)):
    # do handling
    print ('done handling element')

elements = [....]
element_params = [(), (), ...]
pool = Pool()
pool.map(handle_element, zip(elements, element_params))
```

I only see the prints after `map()` concludes.

Is there a way to get more interactive feedback out of `map()`?

**Edit**: Using Python 2.7

Comment: Try with adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after your print. (Python 3 would have a flush-parameter for this purpose)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your problem.  I'm getting the print statement happening during the mapping.

Your example has a few problems:

1. a syntax error with the extra parentheses in the function arguments.
2. Your `handle_element` function should only take one argument.

Using the following code, I was getting output during the execution.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def handle_element(args):
    element, params = args
    # do handling
    print ('done handling element', element, params)
    time.sleep(1.0)

elements = range(100)
params = [('a', 'b')] * 100
pool = Pool()
pool.map(handle_element, zip(elements, params))
```

If there is more to your example that causes the problem, please provide a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Note: I am using Python 3.6.3.

Comment: Do you get interactive printing on 2.7 as well?

Comment: Yes, I do.  I tested it with python 2.7.12.  What happens when you run my code example?